# Display many Pictures in C#

Tags: c#

I have written code to display many image (100 image) with `PictureBox` but when run the application, just one image has been shown...

please help me guys...

Here is my code:

```
    Random r = new Random();

    private  int randomPoint()
    {

        return 1 + r.Next() % 15;

    }

    // x0, y0
    private int[] initialLocation = new int[2];

    private void setLocation(int i)
    {
        int x0 = 50, y0=50;

        initialLocation[1] = y0;
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1: initialLocation[0] = x0;
                break;

            case 2: initialLocation[0] = x0 + 50;
                break;

            case 3: initialLocation[0] = x0 + 100;
                break;

            case 4: initialLocation[0] = x0 + 150;
                break;

            case 5: initialLocation[0] = x0 + 200;
                break;

            case 6: initialLocation[0] = x0 + 250;
                break;

            case 7: initialLocation[0] = x0 + 300;
                break;

            case 8: initialLocation[0] = x0 + 350;
                break;

            case 9: initialLocation[0] = x0 + 400;
                break;

            case 10: initialLocation[0] = x0 + 450;
                break;

        }

    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PictureBox[] p = new PictureBox[10];


        for (int i=0; i<10;i++)  
        {

            p[i] = new PictureBox();
            p[i].ImageLocation = "1.png";

            int[] l = new int[2];

            // create random location for images
            setLocation(randomPoint());

            p[i].Location = new Point(initialLocation[0], initialLocation[1]);

            this.Controls.Add(p[i]);
        }
   }
```

Comment: You can replace that switch statement with a simple multiplication: `initialLocation[0] = x0 + (i-1) * 50;`. Did you realize that you're always using the same image ("1.png")?

Comment: yeah,i know that...my problem is that just one image has been show...

Comment: @hamed - your script will place the same image 10 times, each time in same Y position and one of 10 possible X positions... effectively filling one "square" with the repeated image. Explain what you is your FINAL GOAL here and we'll try to guide you through.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard- I actually wanna display many picture from 15 different location (that create with random numbers and switch case) and then move them and repeat this again...just like that those picture repeatedly create form locations and move.

Comment: Sorry still not clear enough.. got any real example?

Comment: @ Shadow Wizard- first, thank you for trying to help me... Look, actually I have 15 different location (that are same points created in swtich case). 100 image must create at this locations continuously (pictureBox[0..100]). Then every of these images start to move horizontally to reach new point. So I need to repeatedly create and show image at that 15 location and then move them and again do this. (just like 15 parallel produce line)

Answer (score 6):

It's because you are declaring your random number generator every time you want an image:

```
private  int randomPoint()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    return 1 + r.Next() % 15;
}
```

replace this with:

```
private Random r = new Random();

private  int randomPoint()
{
    return 1 + r.Next() % 15;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I understand you correctly you want to display 15 images in a random order across the form.

To ensure that you don't get any repeats you need to make sure that you remove the picture you've picked from the list before picking the next. So (in pseudo code) you need something like this:

```
this.folderList = new List<string>();
// Populate it in an orderly manner

// Create temporary list to put the randomly selected items into
var radomisedList = new List<string>();

// Randomise the list.
var random = new Random();
int num = 0;

while (this.folderList.Count > 0)
{
    num = random.Next(0, this.folderList.Count);
    radomisedList.Add(this.folderList[num]);
    this.folderList.RemoveAt(num);
}
```

This will ensure you get a random order and no repeats.

Comment: thnx ChrisF!!! I do your advice but now when run application, each time random number of images shown (and not 10 images that must shown)...why?!

Comment: @hamed - can you post a screen shot of what you are seeing and a mockup of what you expect to see.

Comment: @hamed: maybe because some get on top of others? Your random numbers are between 1 and 15, and in the setLocation method you only make decisions for i from 1 to 10. If the random number is between 11 and 15, initialLocation will not change and pictures will be on top of the previous.

Comment: @hamed You're probably getting your picture boxes stacked on top of each other now that the position is more random.  Previously, they were probably all stacking on top of each other because of your use of the same random over and over.

Comment: @ChrisF: Does random not always start with a semi-random seed (when no initial parameter is provided)?

Comment: @ChrisF spanks, always forget that. ;D

Comment: @Kurru - yes, but it's time dependent, so **creating a new one** several times in quick succession will always start from the same seed.

Comment: So what I have to do to prevent that? I actually wanna display many picture from 15 different location (that create with random numbers and switch case) and then move them and repeat this again...just like that those picture repeatedly create form location and move.